# Issues with ChatBot Framework in VS 2019

Tags: .net, botframework, visual-studio-2019

I am working to create chatbot using VS2019 and doing initial set up and followed below steps,

Installed VS Enterprise  2019 16.11.19 which installed sdk of 5.0412.

Added Chatbot template from https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=BotBuilder.botbuilderv4.

Now when create project with template EmptyBot all files created
correct but my all dependency files not resolved below is
screenshot.

[image]

And finally throw error of
[image]

However  followed all steps as it mentioned in many articles can anyone help me where I am  wrong

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Installed VS Enterprise 2019 16.11.19 which installed sdk of 5.0412.

As the error message suggests, you cannot target .NET 6.0 when you have installed .NET 5.0. Version 5 is older than version 6, and thus a .NET 5 install would be unable to build a .NET 6 project.

Upgrading to Visual Studio 2022 and .NET 6.0 should solve your problem.